# How to remove added attributes from xml-file when adding new node

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My xml file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>abcdefg </loc>
    <lastmod>2017-12-10</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

After running my program for adding new node it look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>laksdjfs </loc>
    <lastmod> 453w43e5</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap xmlns="">
    <loc>abcdefghoh_20170501181500715.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2017-05-01</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

The **xmlns=""** is added to the  node - and I don't want to have it there. How can I remove it?

My Asp.Net Core 2.0 program look like this:

```
   public void AddIndexFileToSiteMap(string IndexFileName)
    {
        string filenavn = GetSiteMapDir();
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        string lastmoddate = time.Year.ToString("0000") + "-" + time.Month.ToString("00") + "-" + time.Day.ToString("00");

        try
            { 
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filenavn, FileMode.Open);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(fileStream);

            // Create the child nodes. This code demonstrates various ways to add them.
            XmlNode newElem = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"sitemap", "");

            newElem.InnerXml = "<loc></loc><lastmod></lastmod>";
            newElem["loc"].InnerText = IndexFileName;
            newElem["lastmod"].InnerText = lastmoddate;
            newElem.Attributes.RemoveAll();

            // 2.  Add the new element to the end of the item list.
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem);
            fileStream.Position = 0;
            doc.Save(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
            }
        catch 
            {

            }
        //doc.Save(fileStream);
    }
```

Comment: It might be interpreting that it needs to use a different namespace than the default..  I think you need to pass in an XmlNamespace object to the node so that it would infer the default document namespace?  I don't know why the first element wouldn't have the same problem...

Comment: Thanks! Why do I need a namespace?

Comment: All XML elements have a namespace; without a prefix or an explicit xmlns defined, it inherits the default.  I'm not sure the XML API in .NET just assumes without a namespace, that you want to use the default.  I could be wrong; it's been a while since I worked with the API.

Comment: OK - Thanks.......